# Return union of all possible function returns

Tags: typescript

I would like to understand why this fails and the compiler does not infer A as a union like `string[] | number[]`. instead A is inferred as the first return value, in this case `string[]`. Is there a way to fix it?

```
const define = <A>({ handler }: { handler: (some: boolean) => A[] }) => ({ handler });
const a = define({
  handler: (some: boolean) => {
    if (some) {
      return ["foo", "bar"];
    } else {
      return [1, 2];
    }
  },
});
```

[Plaxground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEswJgXhgHgIIA0AfABQDeMAFgIZhwA2CATjAL4BcMFNdjTnJCCAC2CTgCMQIRrQCUWIjDwBtALpt5mReSq0GzDQG4AUKEixqWeMjQJyxmLt7MBQ0RKkywmxWQeOYFCQYQREEeT8AgKYEKABXJjAYZQAiJCkUghgU8WomFNUTKNYYBHoIDEiomBj4xOSARiyAJkL-R1Z-VgJjVllDIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when Typescript is scanning your code, it comes across statement -

```ts
if (some) {
      return ["foo", "bar"];
    }
```

And it goes ahead and tries to infer the type for the generic eagerly, because it's a plain generic (without any sort of constraint), it exacts it to that type, and when it continues to scan, it finds you returning a an array of numbers, so it goes back to check the function definition and sees that the generic type has already been determined, and throws an error.

You can overcome it like this -

```ts
const define = <A extends Array<unknown>,>({ handler }: { handler: (some: boolean) => A }) => ({ handler });

const a = define({
  handler: (some: boolean) => {
    if (some) {
      return ["foo", "bar"];
    } else {
      return [1, 2];
    }
  },
});
```

Here's a [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJpvZN).